# Reading from stdin, and clearing stdin afterward

Tags: c, stdin

Here is a loop that repeatedly gets two characters from `stdin` and outputs them.

```
char buf[2];
while (1)
{
    printf("give me two characters: ");
    fflush(stdout);

    read(0, buf, 2);
    printf("|%c%c|\n", buf[0], buf[1]);
}
```

The problem is that when the ENTER key is struck on the terminal, a newline character is inserted and remains in the `stdin` buffer, and will be grabbed on the next call to `read`. Ideally, I would like to have a clear `stdin` buffer ever time I call read, with none of the previous garbage left over. Can you recommend a *good* solution to this?

I have tried various library calls such as `fgets`, however they encounter the same issue. I was considering using `fpurge` to clear the buffer manually, but I was told this was not a good solution.

The issue here is that leftover input should be treated as garbage, and thrown away. However when I make the next call to `read` I have no way of distinguishing the leftover input from the new input.

Thanks for the input.

Comment: What if your input is coming from a file or being piped from some other process? In these non-interactive cases "clearing stdin" doesn't make as much sense... If I were you I would consider treating the newlines as part of the input that I am parsing instead of trying to trow it out of the buffer like you are asking for.

Comment: @hugomg I see what you mean, however in this contrived example I won't have to be worrying about those issues. In my mind I was looking for something simple, analogous to python's `input()` function. However if the *C* way of doing things is parsing the input manually, then that's what I'll do.

Comment: Why do people think that the need to clear `stdin`, clear from what? Just read all the left bytes and that's it.

Comment: @iharob because those bytes aren't desired anymore. Why go to all the trouble of parsing if you can just clear them?

Comment: So `read()` them. Just `read()` and  discard what you don't need.

Comment: I don't see how `fgets` has the same issue.  Ohhh, you must have done this `char buf[2]; fgets(buf,2,stdin);` Yes, that does have the same issue, but that's not how to use `fgets`.

Comment: Do you want to read exactly two characters, with the read returning as soon as the second character is typed? Or do you want to read the first two characters of a line and then drop the rest of the line? Or something else? You need to have clear requirements to get an accurate solution.

Comment: @rici My apologies. Yes, ideally I would like the entire rest of line to be discarded after read has only the first two characters. The current answer has it so that this works, if the rest of the line is only a single character (so it's not very robust). And I would like read to return after getting those two characters.

Comment: @iharob I see what you were saying now. A second call to read to take out everything left over in the buffer.

Comment: @Cocksure: If you really want to read two characters (i.e., not wait for the user to hit the enter key), you need to unset the `ICANON` flag in the termios settings, and to change `VMIN` to 2. (Or you can change it to 1 and read characters one at a time, which for various reasons is usually a better idea.) There's sample code in Michael Kerrisk's "The Linux Programming Interface", which I recommend if you want to get serious about low-level Linux programming (disclaimer: the author is a friend). The code is online: http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/book/tty/test_tty_functions.c.html

Comment: @rici thanks for the tip! I'll check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add getchar(); to read the more '\n':

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
char buf[2];

main() {
while (1)
{
    printf("give me two characters: ");
    fflush(stdout);

    read(0, buf, 2);
    getchar();
    printf("|%c%c|\n", buf[0], buf[1]);
}
}

give me two characters: ab
|ab|
give me two characters: xy
|xy|
```

Comment: And if someone types a space after the input (and before the newline), it will break. A good way to prevent this is to use `getchar` in a loop until you get a newline.

Comment: @RafaelLerm ah yes, that's an excellent idea. Thanks for your input